# php str_replace

Tags: php, string

i'm using this code to make simple encryption:

```
    function idEncrypt($string)
{
    $multiply = 2457;
    $original = array('1', '2','3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0');
    $replace = array('6', '3', '9', '1', '2', '8', '5', '0', '4', '7');
    $idEncrypt = str_replace($original, $replace, $string);
    //$idEncrypt = $idEncrypt * $multiply;
    return $idEncrypt;      
}
```

it is supposed to take a number, and replace it with the right number from $replace array.
i'm inputting "234", and got "441" for an answer, where i supposed to get "391".

any suggestions ?

Comment: I sure hope you aren't using this for any kind of security applications.

Comment: no no its just for learning..

Comment: If you are interested in substitution ciphers you should check [these](http://scienceblogs.com/goodmath/2008/08/substitution_ciphers.php) [out](http://langref.org/python+ruby+java+php/strings/reversing-a-string/simple-substitution-cipher).

Comment: if i'm using php to write a server, and java to write a client,
what is the best way to encrypt the data being transferred from one to other ?

Comment: Best? Depends what kind of speed you need. If you don't need the speed of UDP, use SSL encryption. (HTTPS) If you are making a game, authenticate/chat over SSL and don't worry about encrypting random game traffic. If you are making something like Skype, you should really learn up on modern encryption and not just wing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `str_replace` is being applied over and over, for each element in the array.

For '234', first 2 is being replaced with 3, and then 3 is being replaced with 9, and then 9 is being replaced with 4.

The 3 is being replaced with 9, and then the 9 is replaced with 4.

Finally, the 4 is being replaced with 1, creating '441'.

Comment: Here's [an example of this](http://us.php.net/str_replace#example-4479) in the docs.

Answer (score 1):

The important bit is found in the docs of the [`str_replace`](http://php.net/str_replace) function:

> #### Replacement order gotcha
>
> Because str_replace() replaces left to right, it might replace a previously inserted value when doing multiple replacements. See also the examples in this document.

For your *simple* "encryption", you want to use PHP's [`strtr`](http://php.net/strtr) function:

```
function transform($string) {
  $original = '1234567890';
  $replace = '6391285047';
  return str_replace($string, $original, $replace);
}
```

nb. Please don't cook your own "encryption" functions. Use established, well-tested algorithms and libraries.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [`strtr`](http://php.net/strtr) instead. You'll need to change your code to have:

```
$original = "1234567890";
$replace = "6391285047";
```

And that's get around the gotcha of `str_replace`.